# SQL pulling distinct values and creating an ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got this query:

```
select
    p.[PersonID],
    d.[DeviceID],
    'DeviceID' + convert(char, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p.PersonID order by d.DeviceID)) as 'key'
from People p
    inner join Devices d
    on p.PersonID = d.PersonID
    where d.DeviceID is not null
```

From these tables:

```
PersonID | Name
---------------
    1       Jim
    2       Bob

DeviceID | PersonID
-------------------
   40         1
   40         1
   70         2
   90         2
```

Gives me these results:

```
PersonID | DeviceID |    key
--------------------------------
    1         40      DeviceID1
    1         40      DeviceID2
    2         70      DeviceID1
    2         90      DeviceID2
```

But actually, because `PersonID` 1 has `DeviceID` 40 twice, I just need this:

```
PersonID | DeviceID |    key
--------------------------------
    1         40      DeviceID1
    2         70      DeviceID1
    2         90      DeviceID2
```

I tried adding DISTINCT to my query but it doesn't work in the first part and I'm not sure how to apply it within the `partition` bit...

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select distinct p.[PersonID], d.[DeviceID],
       concat('DeviceID',  dense_rank() over (partition by p.PersonID order by d.DeviceID)) as [key]
from People p join
     Devices d
     on p.PersonID = d.PersonID
where d.DeviceID is not null;
```

Notice that I also changed the code to use `concat()` rather than `+`.  Your conversion to a string is fraught with peril, because you don't include a length in the conversion.  In SQL Server, the default length varies by context.  Leaving out the length might work in this case.  But if you are in the habit of doing that, it might now work in another case.

Also, use single quotes only for string and date constants.  `key` is a bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.  If you do use it, use square braces or double quotes.

Comment: This won't eliminate the "duplicate" row though

Comment: @Larnu It doesn't eliminate the duplicate row but I can shove DISTINCT at the front to do that. Thanks Gordon!

Comment: I love it when the answer is just a simple cool function I had no idea existed :D

Comment: Also thanks for the advice on `CONCAT()` instead of `+` I've implemented that, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select
    p.[PersonID],
    d.[DeviceID],
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p.PersonID order by d.DeviceID) as RowNum
from People p
    inner join Devices d
    on p.PersonID = d.PersonID
    where d.DeviceID is not null
), WITH CTE2 AS
(
SELECT * FROM CTE where RowNum = 1
)
SELECT *
,'DeviceID' + convert(char, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by p.PersonID order by d.DeviceID)) as 'key'
FROM CTE2
```

I would split it up a bit into parts:

First isolate the rows you want where the deviceid is not null.
Second, grab only the rows you need.
Third, create the "key" and output results.